# fixed table layout isn't matching updated values - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a Matrix component that renders a 2d array passed as props, which works fine, and the table size adapts to whatever the initial values are. However, when I update the props in the parent component, the values in the table update, but not the size of the table itself. However, I have set every element of the table to be fixed width. How do I ensure it matches the size of the table?

```
class Matrix extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <table
            style={{
              border: "1px solid black",
              tableLayout: "fixed",
              width: 400,
              height: 50
            }}
          >
            <tbody>
              {Object(
                this.props.values.map((e, i) => {
                  return (
                    <tr
                      style={{
                        border: "1px solid black",
                        tableLayout: "fixed"
                      }}
                    >
                      {Object(
                        e.map((f, j) => {
                          return (
                            <td style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
                              <MatrixElement value={f} />
                            </td>
                          );
                        })
                      )}
                    </tr>
                  );
                })
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to  update this prop `width: 400,` according passed props on render?

Comment: What do you mean, how do I do this?

Comment: I look at `<table>` tag where you set `width`. You  can try to  set it `auto` or calculate special value according props